# How can I avoid prompting the user multiple times for input?

Tags: c, function

I am creating a simple program which asks for user input in one function `mark` and then passes the input values to a second function `characters` for validation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void marks(float *mark1, float *mark2, float *mark3);
void characters(float mark1, mark2, float mark3);

void marks(float *mark1, float *mark2, float *mark3) {

    float firstMark, secMark, thirdMark;

    printf("Enter mark1, mark2, and mark3: ");
    scanf("%f,%f,%f", mark1, mark2, mark3);

    while (mark1 < 0 || mark2 < 0 || mark3 < 0) {

        printf("Error, marks can't be less than zero \n");
        printf("Enter mark1, mark2, and mark3: ");
        scanf("%f,%f,%f", mark1, mark2, mark3);

        firstMark = *mark1;
        secMark   = *mark2;
        thirdMark = *mark3;
    }
}

void characters(float mark1, float mark2, float mark3) {

    marks(&mark1, &mark2, &mark3);

    if (mark1 < 50 || mark2 < 50 || mark3 < 50) {
        printf("Really Bad! You have failed. \n");
    }
    else if (mark1 > 50 && mark2 > 50 && mark3 > 50) {

        printf("You have passed. \n");
    }
    else {
        printf("ERROR! \n");
    }
}

int main(void) {

    int i;
    float mark1, mark2, mark3;

    printf("Grade list \n");

    marks(&mark1, &mark2, &mark3);
    characters(mark1, mark2, mark3);
}
```

The problem is in `characters` when I call the `mark` it asks for user input, but I only want the program to ask user to enter marks in `main`.

How can I call `marks` in `characters` without the program asking for data input, so that I can use it's parameters to calculate values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to ask the user for the input twice, remove the second call to `marks`. The input has been collected for `characters` by `main` through calling `marks`, and passed through the three parameters; there is no need to call it the second time.

This will fix your problem:

```
void characters(float mark1, float mark2, float mark3) {
    // No second call to marks
    if (mark1 < 50 || mark2 < 50 || mark3 < 50) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I thought we need to call the function every time we need to use them.

Comment: @AamirJohn You do need to call the function each time you want it to do its job, but once the work is done - it's done. The three marks are yours to process until the next time you need to prompt the end-user for the marks again.